# Best way to "eat" something in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

By "eat" I mean: when sprite A (Mario) collides with sprite B (a coin) the collision is detected and the coin is removed from the scene; however, Mario's movement is not altered by the collision with the coin.

At the moment I'm using `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to register when Mario and the coin collide, but this seems to require acknowledging the coin as a physical body - which therefore means that Mario's movement is stopped by it.

Should the coin not have a physics body, and instead should I use a different method to see if they contact?

Comment: What you have described is contact, not collision, as far as SpriteKit is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody)...

> var categoryBitMask: UInt32 A mask that defines which categories this
>   physics body belongs to.
>
> var collisionBitMask: UInt32 A mask that defines which categories of
>   physics bodies can collide with this physics body.
>
> var contactTestBitMask: UInt32 A mask that defines which categories of
>   bodies cause intersection notifications with this physics body.

So if you just set the contactTestBitMask on "Mario" to the coin categoryBitMask, and set the collisionBitMask on "Mario" to 0 (or not to the coin categoryBitMask) you should get be able to tell when the 2 collide in the `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` func but the coin will not impede Mario's movement

Answer (score 2):

Set up **contacts** between Mario and the coin without setting up a **collision**

However, if you wanted the coin to bounce away when Mario hits it, without Mario's movement being affected, you could, in addition to having a contact between Mario and the coin, set up collisions between the coin and Mario **BUT NOT** between Mario and the coin.

If you do this, when Mario hits the coin, Mario's movement will be unaffected but the coin will bounce off Mario via a physics simulation.

You do this by setting Mario's `collisionBitMask` to NOT include the coin's `categoryBitMask`, but have the coins `collisionBitMask` include Mario's `categoryBitMask`.

Note that this 'one-way' collision set up does not work for contacts i.e. if Mario is set up to contact the coin with Mario's `contactTestBitMask` including the coin's category, then it's irrelevant if the coin's `contactTestBitMask` include's Mario's category or not)